# Command to search in files in different dirs but with similar file extension

Tags: bash, grep, webserver

newbie question here.

I am trying to look after a few linux machines but although they are seem similar, they somehow manage to be so different from one another. So for example a mysql log file on one of the servers can be in /var/log/mysql/backups/thelog on the other it can be stored in /var/log/. Now imagine that there are more and more servers.
Good thing is that on 99% of the servers for example the log file extension is .log
So every time i spend alot of time searching where just the logs are stored. dmesg doesn't work on all of this servers and it can't be very helpful. 
So can you help me and tell me some sort of command/script with which i can search in all .log files for example and grep something that might be useful? 
Thank you alot in advance!

Comment: You may just use find command with options to point the file on each server ;  you can also loop around the servers to centralise logs as long-time objective/solution

Comment: `locate mysql.log` is a useful command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `grep`:

- use `-r` to look under each directory

  > -R, -r, --recursive
  >             Read all  files  under  each  directory,  recursively;  this  is
  >             equivalent to the -d recurse option.
- use `--include` option to limit the files

  > --include=GLOB
  >             Search  only  files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard
  >             matching as described under --exclude).

To search for 'text' in `.log` files in any sub-directory of `/var` on one machine, the command will look something like:

```
grep -r --include \*.log 'text' /var
```

You'll have to ssh into each server, and run the `grep`. Command for that'll look something like:

```
for server in $(cat servers.txt); do ssh "$server" "grep-command"> "output-$server"; done
```

Documentation referred from [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html) .

Answer (score 2):

`find` can do a lot by itself:

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec grep -l "pattern" {} +
```

will show you the log files, in or under the current directory, that contain the pattern

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the file and grep the content:

```bsh
for f in $(find -name "*.log"); do grep -n "PATTERN" $f; done
```

Comment: You should not read lines with `for`: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: What about the grep command? I tried with find and it works for showing files name, path and extension which is helpful, but how i can grep specific output from every single file in one shot?